# Which is more secure? AMD DASH or Intel vPro

Tags: hardware, virtualization, firmware

In term of overall security is [AMD DASH](https://www.amd.com/Documents/AMD_DASH_Whitepaper.pdf) or [Intel vPro](http://download.intel.com/products/vpro/whitepaper.pdf) preferable?

They both have:

- Hardware virtualization
- Remote Manageability
- Hardware-enhanced security
- etc...

I can't really distinguish the difference between these two technologies except that AMD is an open standard, what are the main differences and security issues of each of them?

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't provide recommendations. There are tons of sites comparing these two.

Comment: Security isn't a quantifiable property. Either a system is vulnerable to a certain attack or it is not. That makes such [gorilla vs. shark fights](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/) undecidable.

Answer (score 5):

DASH being open standard assures 2 things:

- bugs can be found and fixed pretty fast, with the involvement of the community
- there are no hidden backdoors

vPro has 2 problems:

- is closed source and you cannot check for manufacturer back-doors
- it was already hacked several times

So my vote goes to DASH hands down.